# Ionic Zip .NET: byte array<->string

Tags: .net, string, zip

I zip string to byte array and unzip byte array to string in my .NET application.

Is it possible to check if byte array contains zipped string? 
I.e. I want to avoid double zipping of already zipped string or trying to unzip plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but if I remember correctly the first two bytes of a zip file/stream have a signature. They should always be `PK`.
You could easily check the first two bytes of your byte array and see if they contains the ASCII values 80 (P) and 75 (K)

So supposing your byte array is called `data`

```
if(data[0] != 80 && data[1] != 75)
    // Is not already zipped
```

Comment: yes, it seems correct. Another question: how to recognize was password used to compress ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help on that. Try posting another question.